# LayoutParams returning null

Tags: android

this is my code, but dont know why its returning null? however i can put a null check here, but is there anything wrong?

```
    TextView descriptiontv = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.descriptiontv);
    TextView tc = new TextView(c);
    final PopupWindow windowPopUp = new PopupWindow(tc,LayoutParams.MATCH_PARENT,LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT ,false);

    tc.setBackgroundResource(R.drawable.bg_training_baloon_hc_2x);
    tc.setText("this is a demo test to check how it looks, i m just wanting to test whether it works or not");
    tc.setPadding(20, 20, 20, 20);
    LinearLayout.LayoutParams params = new android.widget.LinearLayout.LayoutParams(LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT,LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT);
    params.setMargins(30, 0, 30, 0);
    tc.setLayoutParams(params);
```

Answer (score 3):

Based on my experience, you have to add the view to its parent view first before you can set the layout parameters for it, like so:

```
TextView calendarYear = new TextView(getActivity());
calendarYear.setText(calendar.getYear() + "");
calendarYear.setTextSize(20);
calendarYear.setTypeface(null, Typeface.BOLD);
calendarYear.setGravity(Gravity.CENTER);
calendarYear.setTextColor(resources.getColor(android.R.color.black));
calendarItemsLinearLayout.addView(calendarYear);

// We have to add the TextView to the layout first before we
// can set the layout margins for it
ViewGroup.LayoutParams layoutParams = calendarYear.getLayoutParams();
((LinearLayout.LayoutParams)layoutParams).setMargins(0, (int)(16 * density), 0, 0);
calendarYear.setLayoutParams(layoutParams);
```

Answer (score 0):

Here

```
tc.getLayoutParams()
```

you haven't given it any `params` yet so it will return `null`. Maybe you meant

```
descriptiontv.getLayoutParams()
```

**Edit**

Try changing

```
params.leftMargin = 30;
params.rightMargin = 30;
```

to

```
params.setMargins(30, 0, 30, 0);
```

And change

```
LinearLayout.LayoutParams params = (android.widget.LinearLayout.LayoutParams)tc.getLayoutParams();
```

to

```
LinearLayout.LayoutParams params = new LinearLayout.LayoutParams(LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT, LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT);
```

Comment: oops, i forget to set layoutparams, how can they be non-null ;)

Comment: I'm not sure what you want. Do you want them to be the same as the `params` for the `TextView` that's created in xml? If so, see my answer again.

Comment: i want to give some margin to textview, but it doesn't seem to be working this way

Comment: You could try initializing your `PopupWindow` after you set everything for your `TextView`. I'm not sure why they aren't working

Comment: Did you get this working yet? You might need to call `update()` on the `PopupWindow()` after changing the `View`